# After updating android studio 3.6.3 and flutter it gives me an error that not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Tags: flutter

```
'C:\Users\lenovo>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli''
```

I have set environment parameter.

Even installed AndroidSdkTools(obsolete)
here is a log of flutter doctor.

```
C:\Users\lenovo>flutter doctor -v)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to resolve the same issue, here is what worked for me:

1. Go to File - Settings - System Settings - Android SDK
2. Select the "SDK Tools" tab
3. Here is the tricky part: for most people with the same problem on the web, you simply need to uncheck the "Hide Obsolete Packages" option on the bottom right corner
   [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gRQE.png). Then, an "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" option will appear [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IVyv.png). Check it, click Apply and then OK. Now, you will be able to run "flutter doctor --android-licenses"
4. For me, number 3 did not work, as the obsolete option did not appear. So I uninstalled the "Android SDK Tools" version which was already installed, the non-obsolete (just unchecked it, clicked apply, etc.). After that, unchecking the "Hide Obsolete Packages" option on the bottom right corner made the "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" appear.

Unfortunately, I did not take a screenshot of the last process and now I cannot reproduce it. Generally, the steps above were a bit "trial and error" and included reinstalling Android Studio at some point or installing the "Android SDK Command-line Tools", but I am not sure about their effect.

edit: Sorry, did not see you mentioned that you already installed the obsolete sdk tools, so my answer is not really useful...